# Send command to stop other process in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, process

In my WPF application, I starts new process which runs batch file.

code is as follows

```
public void startProcess(string batchFileName)
{
     Process proc = new Process();

     //command to execute
     proc.StartInfo.FileName = batchFileName;

     proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     // set up output redirection
     proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

     // see below handler
     proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
     proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

     //start a process
     proc.Start();

     proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
     proc.BeginOutputReadLine();    

     waitThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WaitForProcess));
     waitThread.Start();     
}

 void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // output will be in string e.Data            
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        logsTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SetLogText(UpdateText), DispatcherPriority.Normal, e.Data);
    }
}

private void WaitForProcess()
{
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
}
```

Now I want to stop this newly created process in between. How to achieve that?

Any suggestions/pointers.

Comment: Your question in not clear, do you want `proc.kill();` ??

Comment: Get the correct process object and call process.Kill(); method.

Answer (score 2):

**How to stop a running process**

Close method can be used to stop a process

```
proc.Close();
```

CloseMainWindow can be used to request a stop

```
proc.CloseMainWindow();
```

Kill can be used to destroy the process

```
proc.Kill();
```

**Remarks**

Kill forces a termination of the process, while CloseMainWindow only requests a termination. When a process with a graphical interface is executing, its message loop is in a wait state. The message loop executes every time a Windows message is sent to the process by the operating system. Calling CloseMainWindow sends a request to close to the main window, which, in a well-formed application, closes child windows and revokes all running message loops for the application. The request to exit the process by calling CloseMainWindow does not force the application to quit. The application can ask for user verification before quitting, or it can refuse to quit. To force the application to quit, use the Kill method. The behavior of CloseMainWindow is identical to that of a user closing an application's main window using the system menu. Therefore, the request to exit the process by closing the main window does not force the application to quit immediately.

more info here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.close
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.kill

Comment: Single line answers (whether correct or not) are generally not appreciated on this website. Please read the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page from the Stack Overflow Help Centre to see how you can improve your answers.

Comment: Thanks guys. But my problem is partially solved. My main process starts this new process (as shown above) executing batch file. Commands in batch file contains one more batch file to run. which is still running. How I can close or kill this process.

Comment: I could suggest you to read the batch file and execute commands as processes so you'll have reference to kill them.